# Convert char literal in string to char

Tags: java, string, char

I'm writing a parser for a programming language. I want to create a char literal, just like java's. If I have their input held in a String("a", "z", "1", etc.), I can easily convert this to a char by using charAt(0). But if they give a unicode value, something that is valid in java, how can I convert this to a char? Is there a built in method?

Comment: `Integer.parseInt` on the part after the `\u` then cast it to `char`?

Comment: I was hoping for a way to access the already written code, or a library. But I will have to rewrite it if I can't find anything. Plus, I think there are things other than unicode that java chars support?

Comment: Since uni code value must be an int.Just type casting from int to char might be use full to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) class from [appache commons - lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) for converting unicode char to string

```
public static void main(String[] args){ 
    String unicode = "\u0048\u006C";
    String result = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(unicode); 
    System.out.println(result.charAt(0)); 
    System.out.println(result.charAt(1)); 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use org.apache.poi.util.StringUtil class. 
https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/util/StringUtil.html

download jar from here
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi/3.9

Comment: This is a [link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). You need to explain it here, not just link elsewhere.

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)